# Worksheet_SelectionChange - Timestamp in different column

Tags: vba, excel

I am using the code below to time stamp my employees priority list when they change a task to `Completed`. The code works fine but has to be replicated for each cell that I want to track the changes in.

Ideally, I would like the code to have the exact same functionality but compressed so that I can have it look at a large range, `M5:M2500`, and if cell `M250` is changed to `Completed` have it look through `Y5:Y500` and paste the time stamp in cell `Y250`.

Hopefully this make sense and thanks for any suggestions!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Address = "$M$5" Then
    Call Complete5
    End If
    If Target.Address = "$M$6" Then
    Call Complete6
    End If


    End Sub

    Sub Complete5()
     ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="unlock"
    If InStr(1, Range("$M$5"), "Completed") > 0 Then
        Range("$Y$5").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=NOW()"
        ActiveCell.Select
        Selection.Copy
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Range("$M$5").Select
    Else
        Range("$Y$5").Select
        ActiveCell.ClearContents
        Range("$M$5").Select
    End If
    End Sub
    Sub Complete6()
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="unlock"
    If InStr(1, Range("$M$6"), "Completed") > 0 Then
        Range("$Y$6").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=NOW()"
        ActiveCell.Select
        Selection.Copy
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Range("$M$6").Select
    Else
        Range("$Y$6").Select
        ActiveCell.ClearContents
        Range("$M$6").Select
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Guessing you want `intersect`?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this very cleanly right within the `Worksheet_Change` event itself. This code will evaluate the row in M that was changed and modify the corresponding row in Y accordingly and will also work if a user marks several rows complete at the same time (Ctrl + Enter). *Warning, it will not fire when a user pastes a value into the cell.*

Also, pay close attention to how I removed all the `.Select` and `.Activate` statements and worked directly with the objects themselves.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

With Me

    If Not Intersect(Target, .Range("M5:M2500")) Is Nothing Then

        Application.EnableEvents = False
        .Unprotect Password:="unlock"

        Dim rng As Range, cel As Range
        Set rng = Target

        For Each cel In rng

            If InStr(1, cel, "Completed") Then

                'use offset of 12 columns to get to column "Y"

                cel.Offset(, 12).Value = Now

            Else

                cel.Offset(, 12).ClearContents

            End If

        Next

        Application.EnableEvents = True

    End If

    '.Protect Password:="unlock"

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Scott, this works great! Thanks for taking the time help out.  Always great to learn alternate and more efficient ways to use VBA.

Comment: Great @SteveH - please mark as answered so others know going forward.